# Getting street latitude and longitude as user clicks on it in android

Tags: android, dictionary

In android is it possible to get the latitude and longitude of starting and ending points of a street as it is clicked on the map?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("arg0", arg0.latitude + "-" + arg0.longitude);
            }
        });
```

For more info refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html)

Comment: this would give me the coordinates of a single location. i have to get the lat/long of two loactions starting and ending locations of the street

Comment: @user3847772 I think your requirement is not possible on single click, try it all the best..

Comment: ok. is there any way to change the color of a street as user clicks on it?